Does counter of answers also count deleted answers?
I noticed it at the question Outer semidirect product: the answer counter currently says "2 Answers"; there are indeed two answers, but one of them is closed, hence only visible to high reputation users. What do others see? Is not this confusing for them?

If you log out and then go and look at this question (or just enter incognito mode in your browser), it says that it has 1 answer.  So the number of answers in all cases will be exactly the number of answers that are displayed (and thus depends on whether you have enough reputation to see deleted answers).

it seems that the front page, however, only lists the number of undeleted answers

I confirm both observations. So there seems to be some inconsistency after all, although not the one I expected...

Here is a feature request which is - to some extent - related to this: Please split the answer count shown on posts to distinguish between deleted and undeleted answers.
